# Angularjs Service performing a POST request randomly gets cancelled

Tags: angularjs, http

I have a service that makes a simple POST:

```
saveVersion: function(styleGuideId, data){
    return $http({method: 'post', url: '/style_guides/' + styleGuideId + '/new_version', data: data}).then(function(project){
      console.log('request completed')
    });
  },
```

In the console, if I fire this request, it works fine.

But when I click a button in my ui that makes this request, I see on my server the request gets completed with a 200 but on the client side the browser says it is cancelled.

[image]

The extra GET is also a mystery.  In the console, I trigger the request like this:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get('StyleGuides').saveVersion(sg_id, data)
//sg_id and data are local variables that I got like this:
sg_id = angular.element($0).scope().project.style_guide_id
```

Comment: Can we have a screenshot?

Comment: What is that GET that is also cancelled? Is that part of your code, or part of this mystery? Also, how are you manually triggering the POST from the console, is it using the same code in your app?

Comment: Thats part of the mystery.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you manually POST something from the console unless you're exposing a function and executing that function from the console. Or is there some other way? It looks like you're using Chrome, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: @sunil I just added how to manually access a service via the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out.  Stupid Mistake

The button that triggers the save looked like this:

```
<a href="javacript://" ng-click="saveVersion()">Save</a>
```

See the typo?  changing `javacript://` to `javascript://` fixed the issue.

Comment: Had the same problem using `ng-submit` on a form with `action="#"`.